# Cannot copy postgresql database to new server with error [unrecognized parameter "row_security"]

Tags: postgresql

I'm novice in PostgreSQL. I've succesfully created database, set "philipyoung"—my ID as super user, and use the command below, to copy local database to new server in elephantsql.

```
pg_dump -C -h localhost -U localuser dbname | psql -h remotehost -U remoteuser dbname
```

and then the error below happens

```
SET
SET
SET
SET 
SET
ERROR: unrecognized configuration parameter "row_security"
ERROR: permission denied to create database
ERROR: role "philipyoung" does not exist
FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "xxx.xxx.xxx.xx", user "xxxx", database "xxxx", SSL on
```

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The "row_security" error is probably because you have a newer version of PostgreSQL locally than on the remote end. That's not a problem unless you are using that feature.

The "permission denied" and "user X does not exist" errors are why it is failing. You are trying to restore the database as a user that does not have permission to create a database on the remote server. Then, it can't find the relevant user, and then you haven't set up that user for remote access either.

Users are shared between databases and not copied with them.

So - you want to do something like:

1. Log in as "postgres" on the remote server and "CREATE USER x ..."
2. Restore the database as user "postgres" on the remote server and it should be able to set the ownership to the user you want.

If you do not want to grant remote access to your database you may want to either create a ssh tunnel (lots of examples on the internet) or dump to a file (use "-Fc" for the custom, compressed format) and copy the dump to the remote machine first.

If possible, try to run the same version of PostgreSQL on both servers. It makes things easier if they do need to communicate.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, Richard! Downgrading my Postgre version on local version do the tricks. On totally different context, I used free Heroku service to learn about RESTful API on real world scenario. They didn't give the permission to clone my local database because I'm using the free plan. Is it possible to clone all table to the provided database online? Thanks!

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not a Heroku user - you'll have to read their documentation. Assuming you can't install anything on the Heroku end you'll either end up dropping all the data on the remote end and uploading again or scripting your own difference-generating script.

Answer (score 0):

The same problem I had.. The database was Postgres 9.4 and I have used pgdump and psql from 9.5. Had a lot of problems when trying to import the dump file.
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASyIG.jpg)

Comment: sure it solves the problem because if you export (dump) the database with a client version 9.5 it will add a flag/command in the script which is not supported by 9.4.